# Scala code to auto create cassandra table without giving table definition

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I am beginner in spark and cassandra.working on scenario where I have to persist spark dataframes into cassandra table, without giving table definitions.. is it possible? As my table header keeps changing
Im using datastax cassandra driver.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to save an `RDD` to an existing Cassandra table as well as to let the connector create appropriate table automatically based on the definition of the `RDD` item class.
>
> To save an `RDD` to a new table, instead of calling `saveToCassandra`, call `saveAsCassandraTable` or `saveAsCassandraTableEx` with the name of the table you want to create.

This is from the [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md) of Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector. You can find more details there.